# Full-Width-Responsive-jQuery-Slider not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, responsive-slides

i had used Full-Width-Responsive-jQuery-Slider-Banner-Rotator-Plugin

```
http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Full-Width-Responsive-jQuery-Slider-Banner-Rotator-Plugin.html
```

to get full screen width and i implemented this in my website but i got an issue in this.

There are five dots on images.the slider is following the order of dots and displaying the images.whenever i click on any one of the dots(ie; on 4th dot) on the slider it is not continuing from that dot(ie; not showing 5th image after 4th) instead it is following the order of dots from where it was before(ie; displaying the 2nd one).

Any help would be appreciated.

html code:

```
<div class="banner">
<div class="slider">
<ul>
<li> <a href="#"> <img src="slider01.jpg" width="1920" height="447"> </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> <img src="slider02.jpg" width="1920" height="447"> </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> <img src="slider03.jpg" width="1920" height="447"> </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#"> <img src="slider04.jpg" width="1920" height="447"> </a> </li>
</ul>
<div class="dots"> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="0" class="cur"></a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="1"></a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="2"></a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" rel="3"></a> 
</div>
<div class="arrow"> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-left">&lt;</a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn-right">&gt;</a> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

calling the plugin:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).omSlider({
    slider: $('.slider'),
    dots: $('.dots'),
    next:$('.btn-right'),
    pre:$('.btn-left'),
    timer: 12000,
    showtime: 1000

  });
  </script>
```

Jquery code:

```
$.om = $.om || {};
$.om.slider = function(el, options) {

  'use strict';

  var base = this;
  base.init = function() {
    options = $.extend({
      slider: null,
      dots: null,
      next: null,
      pre: null,
      index: 0,
      timer: 5000,
      showtime: 800
    }, options || {});
    var s,
      inbox = options.slider.find('ul>li'),
      size = inbox.size(),
      b = options.index,
      play = 1,
      movelist = options.dots;

    function move() {
      b++;
      if (b > size - 1) {
        b = 0;
      }
      inbox.each(function(e) {
        inbox.eq(e).hide(0);
        movelist.find("a").eq(e).removeClass("cur");
        if (e == b) {
          inbox.eq(b).fadeIn(options.showtime);
          movelist.find("a").eq(b).addClass("cur");
        }
      });
    }
    s = setInterval(move, options.timer);

    function stopp(obj) {
      $(obj).hover(function() {
        if (play) {
          clearInterval(s);
          play = 0;
        }
      }, function() {
        if (!play) {
          s = setInterval(move, options.timer);
          play = 1;
        }
      });
    }

    if (options.next === null || options.pre === null) {
      options.slider.find('.arrow').hide()
    } else {
      options.next.click(function() {
        move();
      });

      options.pre.click(function() {
        b--;
        if (b < 0) {
          b = size - 1
        }
        inbox.each(function(e) {
          inbox.eq(e).hide(0);
          movelist.find("a").eq(e).removeClass("cur");
          if (e == b) {
            inbox.eq(b).fadeIn(options.showtime);
            movelist.find("a").eq(b).addClass("cur");
          }
        });
      });

      options.slider.hover(function() {
        options.next.fadeIn();
        options.pre.fadeIn();
      }, function() {
        options.next.fadeOut();
        options.pre.fadeOut();
      });

    }

    movelist.find("a").click(function() {
      var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
      inbox.each(function(e) {
        inbox.eq(e).hide(0);
        movelist.find("a").eq(e).removeClass("cur");
        if (e == rel) {
          inbox.eq(rel).fadeIn(options.showtime);
          movelist.find("a").eq(rel).addClass("cur");
        }
      });
    });

    inbox.each(function(e) {
      var inboxsize = inbox.size();
      var inboxwimg = $(this).find('img').width();
      inbox.eq(e).css({
        "margin-left": (-1) * inboxwimg / 2 + "px",
        "z-index": inboxsize - e
      });
    });

  }
}

$.fn.omSlider = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
    new $.om.slider(this, options).init();
  });
};
```

Comment: Why the link is added after `$(document).om`? Are you trying to advertise? :)

Comment: @Morpheus no am not  advertising i will be removing it later..

Comment: I think your problem can be here `<a href="javascript:void(0);"`. Basically, you are telling to return undefined on click.

Comment: @Morpheus so what i need to change can you tell me???

Comment: First try to remove `javascript:void(0);`, secondly I don't see your plugin is doing anything with `dots`. Why can't you use a proper plugin, like http://bxslider.com/

Comment: @Morpheus removing it is not solving my problem!!right now i dont have time to implement a new plugin because the code has been uploaded on server and being used by our customers.if anyone knows the solution it would be appreciated...